# ILGPU in VB.NET basic memory buffer allocation

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to get ILGPU work with VB.NET, but I am struggling even with the basic variable declaration from the tutorials.

This is the C# declaration for the memory buffer. It is pretty straight forward.

```
 // Gets array of 1000 doubles on host.
 double[] doubles = new double[1000];
 // Gets MemoryBuffer on device with same size and contents as doubles.
 MemoryBuffer<double> doublesOnDevice = accelerator.Allocate<double>(doubles);
```

In VB.NET I have the following:

```
 Dim context As New ILGPU.Context
 Dim accel As ILGPU.Runtime.Accelerator = New CPUAccelerator(context)
 Dim dataArray As Double() = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
 Dim dataArrayDevice = accel.Allocate(Of Double)(dataArray)
```

I get an error in the last line saying "is an unsupported type".
I have tried to split it like this:

```
Dim dataArrayDevice As MemoryBuffer(Of Double)
dataArrayDevice = accel.Allocate(Of Double, dataArray)
```

but it does not help. I get the error on the first line on the "of Double", saying also "unsupported type"

Does anybody has a basic example how to allocate the buffer in ILGPU with VB.NET?

Thank you

PS: I have set the Project to x64

Comment: Can you post a complete source of the c# part you think is correct? Someone speaking both languages might then have a chance to help. Closest c# example i found was https://github.com/m4rs-mt/ILGPU/blob/9412fbf04ba9c7f30ab2cb0166871e7ae7f02c05/Docs/Tutorial_02.md . But it does not fit really to what you show.

Comment: Try [`System.Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) instead of `Double` for VB.NET. This is just an educated guess, though.

Comment: @HelO'Ween It would be surprising if that were necessary for VB, since `Double` is a synonym for the system type (should be the same as how `double` is such a synonym in C#).

Comment: ILGPU may not be compatible with VB.  I note that it depends on the `System.Memory` package which includes some Span types.  If I remember right, these require ref structs to work properly.  If it's important to you, see if you can find someone to yell at Microsoft who is big enough where it might motivate MS to make VB work with ref structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that ILGPU is not compatible with VB.NET. You would need to write a C# project which uses ILGPU and reference the C# project in your VB project.

You can also use the project:
https://github.com/MPSQUARK/DataScience

Which provides functionality for any .NET language. It uses ILGPU to provide a fast plug and play solution with various performance optimisations. However it is a WIP.

For help from the community:

Discord: https://discord.gg/X6RBCff

Website: https://www.ilgpu.net/

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading, I come to the conclusion that ILGPU is not compatible with VB.NET.

The solution to my problem is to add a c# library to my VB project where I handle the ILGPU only.